# Copy Files Over FTP in Windows Explorer

Tags: ftp

I remember being able to do something like this years ago:

1. Open windows file explorer (ctrl+e).
2. Go to `ftp://ftp.fooComputer.barServer.com`
3. Just drag over the files.

However, I can't get #2 working. Does it require something installed on the machine I am trying to ftp into? Do I need to go to a specific directory? I CAN connect to the machine via remote desktop (windows both locally and on remote machine).

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Will do, I didn't know we had "Super User" board. Is close my only option now? I can't delete and I don't know how to move between boards.

Comment: Indeed, once you have an "answer", you cannot delete. Try "close" or flag for moderator attention.

Comment: Alright, thanks, I voted to close as well for now.